# Laptop shutsdown suddenly while windows load

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, hardware-failure

My laptop keep shutting down suddenly when windows 7 is loading, two weeks ago it was powering off few minutes after system login but now i even can't see windows login page. It is happening instantaneously like if electricity is gone but i tried booting a live linux distro it works perfectly and i can access my hard drive files but windows still can't start.

PS: I can start windows in safe mode but this doesn't help, i formatted my pc after deleting the C: Partition but again when the system wanted to load the pc powers off. I installed Vista and XP and i have the same problem, Do i have a hard disk issue ? how can i test my system partition of any error, bad sector in a linux live distro ?

PS: I was installing a wrong version of graphic driver, that works only in Vista, in windows Seven during mounts can this be the cause of a hardware failure ?

Answer (score 0):

You have only yet begun to troubleshoot.

First, try the utilities on the [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/).  This will let you do things like check the HDD SMART as well as scan for bad sectors.  If the answer to your question doesn't present just from that, continue below.

1. Don't just format that drive.  Blow away its partition table and set up a new one.
2. Try installing Windows fresh.  If it doesn't work, wipe the drive again and install a Linux distribution to the drive.
3. If Linux starts doing the same thing, you may have a bad drive.

   A. Is the drive bay hot?  You may have a cooling issue.

   B. If not, it's probably a bad drive.

Comment: I will try to run that utility but what is Hdd Smart and how it can help me find hard disk issues ? I can't delete all the partition tables because i have 4 partitions full of data that i don't want to lose but i deleted the system partition and created it again like i said but that didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: [Self-Monitoring Analysis and Reporting Technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.).   If you can access the drive from a hot boot disk like Linux or the [UBCD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/), you can execute data recovery tools against the drive.

Comment: I stared windows XP in safe mode and run this command `wmic diskdrive get status` and result says ok ok that means the hard drive is in good health. I suspect intel graphic driver because when i uninstalled this driver in safe mode i was able to start windows normally but seconds after windows automatically updated the graphic driver to the one i uninstalled ( i don't know why windows keep the uninstalled driver files and why it forces me to get back to the intel driver i uninstalled ???) and then the pc shut down again like before.

Comment: You'll need to manually delete the actual driver file.   Windows likes to hang on to them "just in case", and if it's the "best driver" for the video adapter, it will try to use it.